# Can I use splicing when accessing multiple items in a list of buttons?

Tags: python, list, tkinter

For example:

```
buttons[0:3]['text'] == "X"
```

if not, what are other simple ways to do it?

Comment: Are there buttons in ```buttons```?

Comment: yes, there are.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check several items are equal to some value with [all](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all) function

```py
all(b["text"] == "X" for b in buttons[0:3])
```

Comment: Thank you, I didn't even know such function exists.